# BQ UI - how to delete multiple partitions of the same table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a few processes that yield a partitioned table in BigQuery and, when the datasource has issues I end up with, say 100 partitions of a table that are useless and I need to delete them.

Does anyone know how to achieve that via the BQ UI?

I've tried using the [DML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax) with no result... apparently it only deletes the content within the partitions, not the partitions.

Answer (score 3):

Any particular reasons to physically delete the partitions instead of clear content? Alternatively, you can try

```
bq rm -f -t [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE]$[20170101]
```

Comment: @FKrauss: Find the related documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#deleting_a_partitioned_table)

Comment: yes it is clear how to delete 1 partion, the question is how to delete 100 partions without repeating it. it costs about 30 minutes to delete 100 individual partitions. Also what do you mean with "clear content"? A delete statement? That is costly